# R function will not coerce sf data.table

Tags: r, function, r-sf

I am trying to coerce only certain columns in my sf data.table from character to numeric.  When I write the code out without a function it works.

`columns <- c("STATEFP",  "COUNTYFP", "TRACTCE", "BLKGRPCE", "GEOID", "ALAND", "AWATER", "INTPTLAT", "INTPTLON") 
for (i in columns){ sfphl[[i]] <- as.numeric(sfphl[[i]])}`

when I load this same code into a function it does not work anymore.

```
    col_conv <- function(x){
        columns <- c("STATEFP",  "COUNTYFP", "TRACTCE", "BLKGRPCE", "GEOID", "ALAND", "AWATER", "INTPTLAT", "INTPTLON")
          for (i in columns){
            x[[i]] <- as.numeric(x[[i]])
          }
        }
col_conv(sfphl)
```

I'm probably missing something with my function, I've tried using return(x) or just x at the end of my function to no avail.  I don't think this has to do with the data.table being a simple feature but it could be.

Comment: This looks like a scoping error. In R, you can't use functions to modify their inputs in this way. What if you do `return(x)` inside your function and then do `sfphl <- col_conv(sfphl)`?

Comment: Yes this works, thanks guys.